# Regular expression to match numeric columns

Tags: php, regex, numbers

Need regular expression that matches the numeric columns only.
Each row of the numeric columns may or may not contain the decimal point plus minus  sing and the letter "e".
Also the number of white spaces between each column may happen to be more than one. And the number of columns is not fixed.

Representative sample of the text I am parsing.

```
  #B0 alphanumeric line 26_0000 abc
#B1  57 115 550.000000 270.000000 
#N 18
#Labels X Y  Something  Else Here
-16.3252 -11.205718    0 2.61836e-07 110
-16.1728 -10.90549    0 2.61836e-07 87 
-16.0228 -10.605516    0 2.61836e-07 50 
-15.8728 -10.305796    0 2.61836e-07 31
-15.7229 -10.005822    0 2.61836e-07 49 
-15.5727 -9.705594    0 2.51826e-07 4998
-15.4228 -9.40562     0 2.71836e-07 176

Some alphanumeric  -14.9729 is 24678   COM at -14.7531   
Sum = 147364  Ave.Mon./Time = 136117
```

Comment: [What you have tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I know that  /\d*(?:\.\d+)*$/ matches decimal numbers. For the list of characters that   I can use /[\.\+\-e]/ And matching one or more blank spaces /\s+/ But I fail in combining all of that in a single regular expression.

Comment: Do you need a regular expression for this; what are you paying? Or do you want help trying to write one yourself; what have you got so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little unclear exactly what you're asking for, but let me at least point you in the right direction...

You know that this:

```
\d*(?:\.\d+)*
```

matches a decimal number. So, you could then extend this to also match negative numbers like so:

```
-?\d*(?:\.\d+)*
```

And you could then extend this further to match numbers that have "e-..." at the end, like so:

```
-?\d*(?:\.\d+)*(?:e-\d+)?
```

Then finally, if you want to search for a whole line that onle contains numbers like this, separated by whitespace, you could use:

```
^(?:-?\d*(?:\.\d+)*(?:e-\d+)?\s*)*$
```

Comment: Thanks. Good starting point. Will post the exact solution once I get it all clear.

Comment: That is the exact solution for this problem. What I was stumbling was the modifier.